# ExtJS4 Window does not close in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, extjs4

I have to fix some problems in somebody's code. In the Internet Explorer (9-11) some ExtJS Window don't want to close on clicking the X in the top-right corner.

What is the problem, what should I do?

I think, the problem is when I open modal windows, maybe. If there is only one window, the X works fine. How can I fix this problem?

If the close is on an other button or escape, close works, but I need the X, too.

Comment: can be a million things... no errors in the console?

Comment: There's no any error, unfortunately

Comment: You are going to need to post the relevant code, if you want us to be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

It could be because of multiple windows opened and overlapped one on another. When you close one window you will not be able feel that it got closed, in fact it might have closed and showing another window. Since it is not possible to open multiple windows in modal, its seems to be working. You have to write code to manage  it manually. Preferable way is to use modal window.